# Full settings missing in iPhone Simulator 4.0.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, ios-simulator

I believe I remember running the iPhone Simulator (perhaps version 4.0) on a macbook some months ago and was able to get to the full settings (mail specifically) them. Now, having installed the iOS4 SDK and running the 4.0.2 Simulator, I do not see the "mail, contacts and calendar" settings regardless of whether I choose the iPhone, iPad, or iPhone4. Switching to version 3.2 does not produce these either.

Am I completely mistaken about ever seeing the Mail settings in the iPhone Simulator or was something changed? I do not need to send mail however I simply need to take screenshots of how to set up mail but do not have a physical iPad to take screenshots.

Is there anything else I might be able to do/use? I have borrowed an iPhone to take screenshots however would really like to also show screenshots for iPad (the same really but my concern is primarily for aesthetics).

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen Mail settings in the iPhone Simulator.  I'd just try to borrow one or plea to the twitter community for some screenshots.